# webpack "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory"

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, webpack

I successfully followed and executed 6 of the 7 SPX tutorials. In the last one "Document Card Example", I get the following error during build:

```
[16:20:50] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[16:20:51] Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 806 ms
[16:20:51] Starting subtask 'webpack'...
[16:20:53] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./lib/webparts/documentCardExample/DocumentCardExampleWebPart.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'set-webpack-public-path' in 'D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\lib\webparts\documentCardExample'
resolve 'set-webpack-public-path' in 'D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\lib\webparts\documentCardExample'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\package.json (relative path: ./lib/webparts/documentCardExample)
  after using description file: D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\package.json (relative path: ./lib/webparts/documentCardExample)
    resolve as module
      D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\lib\webparts\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\lib\webparts\documentCardExample\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\documentcardexample-webpart\lib\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\spfx\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\Dennis\OneDrive - Paeroa Community Support Trust\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

If I run the "Document Card Example" from a Git clone, it works. If I try to run the "React-Todo-Basic" sample from the same clone, I get a very similar the same error as above:

```
[16:01:36] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[16:01:37] Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 945 ms
[16:01:37] Starting subtask 'webpack'...
[16:01:46] Error - [webpack] 'dist':
./lib/webparts/todo/components/TodoContainer/TodoContainer.module.scss.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./TodoContainer.module.css in D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-todo-basic\lib\webparts\todo\components\TodoContainer
resolve file
  D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-todo-basic\lib\webparts\todo\components\TodoContainer\TodoContainer.module.css doesn't exist
  D:\sp-dev-fx-webparts\samples\react-todo-basic\lib\webparts\todo\components\TodoContainer\TodoContainer.module.css.webpack.js doesn't exist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are issues for two specific scenarios in this issue, so let's tackle them one-by-one. First would recommend ensuring that you have the latest version of the Yeoman templates by executing npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint, which will update your Yeoman package for the tutorial work.

**Issues around the Document Card tutorial**

- https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/use-fabric-react-components.

There were some issues around the steps due to the recent update to webpack 2.x so just updated the tutorial steps to reflect those changes. Would recommend retesting the tutorial after package update with updated guidance.

**Issues around the react-todo-basic**

This has been indeed updated to GA version and should work without any issues. I just pulled the version down to a clean machine and tested that with gulp serve without any issues. Could it be that you are using different node or npm versions than recommended in our development environment setup?

- https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment

Comment: Hi Vesa, thanks for your time. I downloaded the standard version during the last couple of days. I just run _gulp serve_ in the **react-todo-basic** and it showed the following versions, plus the npm:
`Project react-todo-basic version: 0.0.1
Build tools version: 2.5.3
Node version: v6.11.0
npm version: 5.0.3`
I try to redo the Document Cards tomorrow morning :-)

Comment: Hi Dennis, was able to figure out the issue in the react-todo-basic after some investigation with clean W10 machine. There were some accidental files checked to GitHub which should not be in there... leftovers from the webpack execution. There are two ways to now solve this. #1) pull down latest version for GitHub or #2) run gulp clean and then your local version is cleaned. That will remove unnecessary files and you'll be good to go again.

Comment: Cheers Vesa, `gulp clean` worked like a charm for **react-todo-basic** :-) I should get back to redo the **Document Card** soon.
A quick off topic question, if you can. I am evaluating SPFx to find out if it is supporting the sharepoint features we like. Does SPFx at the current stage support Enterprise Keywords fully? Could I code a WebPart to use (new,edit,view) Enterprise Keywords?

Comment: Thanks Vesa, I followed the updated tutorial and it worked sweet as. Local Workbench, Online Workbench and deployed using Azure CDN. Keep up the great work :-)

Answer (score 0):

The sp-dev-fx-webparts git repository contains examples build using developer preview version of SPFx (from drop 5 and RC0). From then the SPFx code changed a lot and SPFx is still under development.

The tutorials are to give you an idea how to work in SPFx environment. In order to run those tutorial, [follow this git tutorial to update RC0 build to GA](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-GA).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I did the tutorials "manual", with the latest downloads, from earlier this week. The 7th tutorial gives me the error with webpack, that it can't find the images. When I run it from the Github clone it works. I can't find/see a difference and any pointer would be appreciated.

The React-Todo-Basic states in the Readme.md that has been updated to GA recently:
1.0.2|May 4th, 2017|Updated to SPFx GA
1.0.1|February 1st, 2017|Updated to SPFx drop RC0
1.0.0|October 12th, 2016|Initial release

Is there maybe somewhere a webpack option I'm missing?

Comment: can you confirm you are referring to same git directory? [Git SPFx WebPart Tutorials](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/tutorials)

Comment: Yes it was the correct rep. Thanks for the help :-) Sorry I got the time locker when replying before :-)

Comment: I tested the repository for Document Card web part and its working fine. I run into an issue, when my command prompt is not opened as administrator. It was not able to download few of the dependencies. Try running your `command prompt as administrator`, delete the `node_module` folder and finally run command `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

gulp clean saved my day when I got this error in one of my own projects that were copied between machines!